# How to do custom paging in webgrid and place a dropdownlist for navigating page on selected page number

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I just want to place a dropdown list on my page and when i select any page number from dropdownlist , it should display appropriate page from webgrid. MVC3

Comment: I was just thinking about this and suddenly got a idea... If anybody is also trying for the same then this will help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//For displaying Dropdown List...
@{
int i = 1;
<select id="number">
@for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
<option value=@i>
 @i
</option>    
}
</select>}



//Jquery for navigating on page selected by dropdownlist...
<script language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
$("#number").change(function () { // Number is the name of dropdownlist control
var selectedvalue = $('#number').val(); // Value selected by control
            value = '/student?page=' + selectedvalue; // Here student is my controller name
$('#editlink').attr('href', value);   // For rendering on a Action Link.
});
});</script>



//Action Link.....
@Html.ActionLink("Go", "student", "page=", new { ID = 0 }, new { id = "editlink" })
// edit link is the link name used in Jquery.
```